# Can I move a Terraform binary file from one computer to another?

Tags: terraform, binaryfiles, terraform-provider-gcp

I am adding a service to a provider, but since the API has some missing operations, I won't be able to publish it to the Terraform registry. As a temporary solution, can I "copy" the binary file that is generated locally to another computer and expect it behave the same way? Assuming both systems have the same OS, similar architecture and same Terraform version.

The expected behaviour is to be able to create resources of the service that I newly added on the new system after the Terraform binary has been copied into it.

Answer (score 0):

Terraform allows [custom provider installation configuration](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/config/config-file#provider-installation) specified in [the CLI configuration file](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/config/config-file). (Note: this is separate from your `.tf` files that you use to define Terraform modules.)

If you configure Terraform to use a "filesystem mirror" then you can place the provider executable at a path that matches the "unpacked layout" described in the documentation.

Comment: I added this ```provider_installation { filesystem_mirror {
    path    = "<provider-executable-file-path>"
  }
  direct {}
}```
But I seem to be getting a Failed to load provider plugins error. I also tried to use the dev_override block like this `dev_overrides {
    "hashicorp/google" = "<provider-executable-file-path>"
  }` but I get the same error here

Comment: The `path` argument in `filesystem_mirror` expects a path to the directory containing your entire filesystem mirror, not a path directly to your executable. You will need to construct a directory layout matching what is documented as the "unpacked layout" and then set `path` to refer to the _top-level_ directory, which for `hashicorp/google` would be the directory that contains a subdirectory named `registry.terraform.io` (the hostname of the registry that `hashicorp/google` comes from).

Comment: If you're not sure how to proceed from here then it would help to edit your question to include the full CLI configuration you tried and also information about the relevant directory trees on your hard disk so I can see whether you've constructed the unpacked layout correctly.